# Right align / left align - stick to one - also bring back the X

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently there was a post on ux about the nice X at the top right corner of a dialog:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/90153/are-close-and-x-on-a-popup-redundant

The consensus from that post is that it is almost never recommended to remove the X in dialog boxes, but it is okay to have the X and include a Cancel or Close button.

The **Match Preferences** dialog on jobs has it, but the ask question dialog for jobs doesn't:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Can all the so/se dialogs please consider adding this.  Also why are the buttons on some dialogs left aligned while other dialogs right aligned.  I think it would be a good idea to maintain a consistant user experience across the network by maybe right aligning all popup dialogs.  Seen in the image above it looks good, but here's the Match Preferences dialog:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Please change this and all other dialog's to right align the buttons / links.